# Como evitar mostrar database error en codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

alguien podría ayudarme a solucionar un problemas, cada vez que trato de entrar al sistema ya sea mediante un servidor local o remoto, a veces el servidor demora en conectarse a la base de datos y el sistema que esta programado en codeigniter 3, empieza a mostrar un error como este

[image: database error]

pero si actualizo el navegador, como ya se conecto el servidor a la base de datos después de un tiempo normal puedo visualizar el sistema, quisiera saber si hay alguna manera de evitar ese error o modificar ese error para que muestre otra visualización como espere un momento esta conectándose a la base de datos y después cuando se logre la conexión se visualice el sistema normalmente o caso contrario si el servidor se conecto rápidamente con la bd, que no muestre ningún mensaje y que solo se visualice el sistema normalmente.

Espero puedan ayudarme por favor...

---

aqui muestro la imagen del error [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código de conexión:

```php
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'ci-examen',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => FALSE,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Comment: Puedes mostarnos el codigo en donde estableces la conexion a la base de datos? talvez algo estas haciendo mal

Comment: según la [documentación](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/errors.html) "la configuración del error reporting está al principio del index.php principal" esto depende de la variable de entorno [`CI_ENV`](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/index.php#L59)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En codeigniter 3 se muestran esos mensajes porque en tu archivo `application/config/database.php` el parámetro `'db_debug'` debe generar TRUE. Por defecto el código viene así:

```
'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production')
```

(genera TRUE)

Puedes convertirlo a FALSE directamente:

```
'db_debug' => FALSE
```

O puedes establecer la variable ENVIRONMENT de 'development' a 'production'
[como indica en la documentación](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/environments.html)
O también puedes crear/modificar un archivo .htaccess, ubicado en la raíz de tu proyecto con la siguiente línea de código:

```
SetEnv CI_ENV production
```

COMPLEMENTACIÓN DE LA RESPUESTA:
Si abres el archivo index.php ubicado en la raíz del proyecto, notarás el siguiente switch:

```
switch (ENVIRONMENT) {
    case 'development':
        error_reporting(-1);
        ini_set('display_errors', 1);
        break;
    case 'testing':
    case 'production':
        ini_set('display_errors', 0);
        if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3', '>=')) {
            error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT & ~E_USER_NOTICE & ~E_USER_DEPRECATED);
        } else {
            error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_USER_NOTICE);
        }
        break;
    default:
        header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.', TRUE, 503);
        echo 'The application environment is not set correctly.';
        exit(1); // EXIT_ERROR
}
```

Como se nota, cuando el valor del `ENVIRONMENT` se encuentra en `production`, se desactivan los mensajes `debug - warning - notice - error` del funcionamiento.

Por eso es mejor agregar al final del archivo raíz .htaccess la línea:

```
SetEnv CI_ENV production
```

(Si no tienes un archivo .htaccess en la raíz de tu proyecto, crea uno).

Comment: Gracias por responder hice lo que mencionaste, sin embargo, sigue mostrado el error

Comment: hay una inconsistencia entre la documentación enlazada ( habla de `CI_ENVIRONMENT ` ) y el código ( será la versión? ), en el source se chequea la variable [`CI_ENV`](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/index.php#L56)

Comment: La variable CI_ENV es la que se define como variable para APACHE. Codeigniter verifica si esta definida CI_ENV en apache y define para el proyecto la variable ENVIRONMENT. Es algo confuso, pero es correcto. Lo puedes notar abriendo el archivo index.php ubicado en la raíz de tu proyecto.

Comment: Estimado Diego. He complementado mi respuesta para que te aclare la duda. Abriendo el archivo index.php ubicado en la raíz de tu proyecto se te pueden ocurrir algunas ideas de como solucionar ese inconveniente.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo erick, me faltaba agregar ese código en el htaccess, ahora si ya no muestra el error cuando el servidor demora en conectarse a la base de datos